# has_many through association before persistence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Before a `:through` relationship has been persisted, is it still possible to return the association?

Here is a simplified version of the class structure:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quxes
  has_many :bars, through: :quxes
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  # there is no has_many :quxes -- this class doesn't care
end

class Qux < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :bar
end
```

So, I want to make calls like `foo.bars` which is equivalent to `foo.quxes.map(&:bars)`

I'm cloning `Foo`s, but not saving them. `Qux`s are copied from `old_foo` to `new_foo` by

```
new_foo.quxes << old_foo.quxes.map(&:dup)
```

Please note that the above results in:

```
new_foo.quxes.first.foo == new_foo

new_foo.quxes.first.foo_id == old_foo.id
```

which shows that the association exists, but is not yet persisted.

It seems to me you should now be able to do:

```
new_foo.bars # same as new_foo.quxes.map(&:bar)
```

But it actually returns `[]`

Is it possible for this association `new_foo.bars` to work before `new_foo` and its new `quxes` are saved? Is this even expected/desirable behavior for `:through`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `through` relation still "works" in the sense that you can manipulate it normally. I think what you mean is that it doesn't contain any `bars` added to any of the `quxes`. This is because the relation `bars` is separate from the relation `quxes` even if its not independent. To put it another way, `bars` is not simply `quxes.map(&:bar)`, as you say; it runs a totally separate query, something like:

```
> puts foo.bars.to_sql
SELECT "bars".* FROM "bars" INNER JOIN "quxes" ON "bars"."id" = "quxes"."bar_id" WHERE "quxes"."foo_id" = 1
> puts new_foo.quxes.to_sql
SELECT "quxes".* FROM "quxes" WHERE "quxes"."foo_id" = 1
```

This means that unless an associated `bar` is persisted, the `bars` relation's SQL won't pick it up:

```
> persisted_foo.quxes.first.build_bar
#<Bar id: nil>
> persisted_foo.bars
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
> persisted_foo.quxes.first.save!
> persisted_foo.reload
> persisted_foo.bars
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Bar id: 1>]>
```

Comment: I found the same issue / solution. When running some tests I was trying to use a "Fabricate.build", which works for 1:N relations, but not for 1:N:N or 1:N-through.